# How do I use a python file I created in the interpretor?

Tags: python

Is there a way to import a python file I created in an editor to the interpretor for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start the Python console and have a file executed, so its variables are available to you, use `-i`:

```
$ cat foo.py
a = [1,2,3]
b = 42
print('Hello world')
$ python -i foo.py
Hello world
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
42
>>> quit()
```

If you are already inside the interpreter, use `execfile`, like this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:48:52)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile('foo.py')
Hello world
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
42
```

If you just want to use some variable from the file, use `import`, like this:

```
>>> from foo import a,b
Hello world
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
42
```

*Note that this will execute the file, that's why you see `Hello world` printed.*

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Say you have script.py which has function foo(). Go to the appropriate directory and start up the IDLE by running python

```
>>> import script
>>> script.foo()
```

As a side note, I strongly prefer IPython as my IDLE of choice. In this example, it would show you all the options available if you type "script." THEN tab. IPython strongly mimics command line behavior in the IDLE (such as running ls).